# She is in /on the left side of the picture?

Tags: prepositions

In what preposition should I use when referring to a picture / photo description or a person who's located in / on one of its sides.

> She is **in** the left side of the picture

Or

> She is **on**  the left side of the picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We normally speak of someone being *in* a photograph rather than "on". What may change things slightly here is that you are referring to a particular part of the photo, the left. We always say "*on the left*", never "*in the left*", as that is simply incorrect.

What you see as the left side of a photograph isn't technically the left. The person to the left in a photo was standing on the right when it was taken! So if you are describing a person's position in a photograph technically I suppose you should say "*on* the left of the photo", because you are referring to the printed photograph rather than what it depicts.

Comment: Which preposition should be used in the following simple pattern: (I am standing at the center of the room saying to someone) "The table is standing on the left and the wardrobe - on the right" or shall it be "to the left/right"?       Thank you.